# How to Connect into a MySQL in azure server using SQLAlchemy

Tags: azure, flask-sqlalchemy, azure-mysql-database

I need some help. I created a CRUD with Flask, and I want to conect it with my MySQL in azure. I new using Flask, so I don't know how to do it. Somebody can help me?

Now, I tried to do this:
**app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']'mysql://Myuser@Myuser:MyPasswrd@MyDataBase:3306/mySchema'**

My localhost works, so, I tried to change the username,passwrd and database and thought that it would work. But it didn't. I can access my Mysql-azure via workbench btw.
Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 0):

I tried it here, and I got an error, I'll put a photo here. idk if this errors is because I dont have a MySQL connection, or something (I was using but I removed to see if it would work). Here a print of my instance.py and the error [Instance of server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2N58.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It should work after installing mysql-connector.

```
pip install mysql-connector
```

change the SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI in your python script to below and create your database.

```
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "mysql+mysqlconnector://{username}:{password}@{server}/testdb".format(username, password, server)
```

let me know if you see any specific error

Comment: One question, I have to use these .format()? Cause when I not use I receive the error Can't connect to MySQL server on '{my-db}:3306' (-2 Name or service not known)